# Windows cmd bat call command with /?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, call

I understand that

=> call /?

will show the help message for the call command.
But

=> call SubBatch params /?

Also shows the help message, either at the command prompt or within a bat file.

This can be annoying if i have a bat file that calls another bat file, but the user invoked the first bat file with /? somewhere in the linend
Eg. if i have a batch file named main.bat containing:

```
echo Starting my batch file
call SubBatch %*
```

If i invoke "main p1 p2 /?" or "main abc/?def" I get the call help text.  I can avoid this (ie. seeing the call help) by putting the string containing the /? in quotes:  "/?" or "abc/?def" but that string could be anywhere in the param string %*

Are there other way to handle this?

I would like

=> call sub params /? params

should call the sub and not show the call help msg.

Comment: Your `params` don't appear to be quoted. Have you tried doing that? e.g. ```call "main.bat" "p1 p2 /?"``` or ```call "main.bat" "abc/?def"```. _For the former example, you may need to include additional code in `main.bat` to parse/remove the enclosing quotes, if you need to separate the individual arguments._ You could of course quote each individually too, ```call "main.bat" "p1" "p2" "/?"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CALL late percent expansion, then the CALL command doesn't detect the `/?`.
Btw. It also has the advantage of less modifying arguments.

```
@echo off

set "args=%*"
call %%args%%
```

Examples

```
myBatch.bat echo This is a test /?
myBatch.bat echo /? Show help for the ECHO command
```

Comment: Thanks, jeb - that seems to handle my test cases.  The sub receives the params that the main got from the user.